# Read text file and import into JList?

Tags: java, text, jlist

I am looking to read data from a text file, and import it into a JList, and am running into a number of issues. Here is what I have so far:

```
    String stringpath = "C:/StackOverflowQuestion.txt";
    Path path = Paths.get(stringpath, args);

    List<String> readText = Files.readAllLines(path);
    for (String elem : readText){
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
```

I am using this for testing, and I cannot seem to get the file contents to print even to the console output window. What am I missing? No errors are being generated.

Edit: I got it to work under a button. How come it will not work in the main method of my JFrame class?

Edit: Posting full code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Forms;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class RemoteDesktop extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Home
     */
    public RemoteDesktop() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setIcon();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        backButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        connectButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        resultList = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setName("Home"); // NOI18N
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(585, 360));

        backButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        backButton.setText("Back");
        backButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                backButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        connectButton.setText("Connect");
        connectButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                connectButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("Computer name or IP address:");

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Forms/Capture.PNG"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setText("Select a computer from the list below or type it in manually.");

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(resultList);

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        jMenuItem1.setText("Exit");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(backButton)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 129, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(connectButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addGap(41, 41, 41)))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(backButton)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 24, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 62, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                        .addComponent(connectButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 226, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void backButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Home homeFrame = new Home();

        homeFrame.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);

    }                                          

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
    }                                          

    private void connectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            File file = new File("P:/IT/Shared Knowledge/FILE SHARE/computers.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }                                             
    private void setIcon() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("SelfService.png")));
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RemoteDesktop.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RemoteDesktop.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RemoteDesktop.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RemoteDesktop.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>





        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RemoteDesktop().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton backButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton connectButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> resultList;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Any errors? Like fnf or something similar?

Comment: No errors at all. I have tried several ways of doing this, it appears there is 10+ ways of reading data from a file, and not sure which to choose.

Comment: Am I to use buffered readers, stream readers, Files class,....?

Comment: Works fine for me... I made my own txt file, but it works fine

Comment: This code is in the main method of my .java class

Comment: @RC. args has been removed, and still does not work.

Comment: What is contained in the text file you are reading?

Comment: It is just plain text, computer names. Ok, so I put the code underneath a button and it works now. How can I get the code to run when the Jframe opens, and not after I click the button?

Comment: In order to get an answer, I suggest you edit your question, and post you actual code (the jframe etc the whole *not working* thing), my guess is that you did put the code after the "UI loop" start or something like that

Comment: @RC. posted the full code, sorry about the wall of text. :(

Comment: @RC. Where would I place the code under the 'confirmButton' so that it runs when the frame opens?

Comment: Apache FileUtils works well.

Answer (score 0):

This should read form the file and print it out. This is mod of your code above. You may need to use a different file path of the working dir.

```
    String stringpath = "C:/StackOverflowQuestion.txt";
    ArrayList<String> readText = new ArrayList<String>();
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stringpath)))
    {
        String temp =br.readLine();
        while(temp == null)
        {
            readText.add(temp);
            temp =br.readLine();
        }


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    for(int i =0;i<readText.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(readText.get(i));
    }
```